# gear icon missing ubuntu 14.04 from login

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu

ok im done looking .... I'm missing the little gear icon on the login menu/window. I'm trying to load up lubuntu. Is their a terminal command to do this? or is their a terminal command for the little gear icon. I all ready did this part "sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop".

Comment: OP, assuming you dont have a ton of software or files installed on the system, Id reccomend just installing Lubuntu instead of messing with installing the desktop on Unity.

Answer (score -1):

Run this in the terminal to access settings

```
    gnome-control-center
```

Comment: You cant select your desktop environment from the Settings Menu. The only way to do so is by changing it on the Login screen, thats his problem.